# Can not find shortest route through Maze if an obstacle is present using DFS C++

Tags: c++, vector, depth-first-search, path-finding

I am currently working on a prject that will find the shortest route through a maze and then output the route. It works perfectly for mazes that do not feature any obstacles such as:

```
xxxxxxx
xA...Bx
xxxxxxx
```

and

```
xxxxx
x...B
A...x
xxxxx
```

However, for the following mazes:

```
xxxxxxxxxx
x........x
x..xxxx..x
x..xxxx..x
A..xxxx..B
x..xxxx..x
x........x
x........x
xxxxxxxxxx
```

and

```
xxxxxxxBxxx
x.........x
x...xxxx..x
x...xxxx..x
x....A....x
x..xx.xx..x
x.........x
x.........x
xxxxxxxxxxx
```

It provides a route that is correct but not the shortest. I'm not sure why this is and any help is greatly appreciated.

Please find my full code attached:

```
#include<fstream>
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include <vector>
//Maze Size
#define SIZE 5
using namespace std;

bool isSafe( vector<vector<char>> maze, vector<vector<int>> visited, int x, int y);
bool isValid(int x, int y, int rows, int columns);
void findShortestPath(vector<vector<char>> maze, vector<vector<int>> visited, int i, int j, int x, int y, int& min_dist, int dist, string& p_route,string route, int rows, int columns);
void userInput();
void createMaze(int rows, int columns, string filename);



int main()
{
    userInput();
}

bool isSafe(vector<vector<char>> maze, vector<vector<int>> visited, int x, int y)
{
    if (maze[x][y] == 'x' || visited[x][y] || maze[x][y] == NULL)
        return false;

    return true;
}

bool isValid(int x, int y, int rows, int columns)
{
    if (x < rows && y < columns && x >= 0 && y >= 0)
        return true;

    return false;
}

void findShortestPath(vector<vector<char>> maze, vector<vector<int>> visited, int i, int j, int x, int y, int& min_dist, int dist,string&p_route,string route, int rows, int columns)  //I&J Start Point, X&Y End point
{
    // if destination is found, update min_dist
    


        if (i == x && j == y)
        {
            p_route = route;
            min_dist = min(dist, min_dist);
            if (p_route.length() == min_dist)
            {
                if (min_dist != INT_MAX)
                {
                    cout << "The shortest path from source to destination has length " << min_dist << endl;
                    cout << "The route through the maze is: " << p_route << endl;
                    cout << p_route.length();

                }
                else
                {
                    cout << "Destination can't be reached from given source";
                }
                exit(0);
            }
            else  
            return;
        }

        // set (i, j) cell as visited
        visited[i][j] = 1;

        // go to bottom cell
        if (isValid(i + 1, j, rows, columns) && isSafe(maze, visited, i + 1, j))
            findShortestPath(maze, visited, i + 1, j, x, y, min_dist, dist + 1, p_route, route.append("S") , rows,  columns);

        // go to right cell
        if (isValid(i, j + 1, rows, columns) && isSafe(maze, visited, i, j + 1))
            findShortestPath(maze, visited, i, j + 1, x, y, min_dist, dist + 1, p_route, route.append("E") , rows,  columns);

        // go to top cell
        if (isValid(i - 1, j, rows, columns) && isSafe(maze, visited, i - 1, j))
            findShortestPath(maze, visited, i - 1, j, x, y, min_dist, dist + 1, p_route, route.append("N"),  rows,  columns);

        // go to left cell
        if (isValid(i, j - 1, rows, columns) && isSafe(maze, visited, i, j - 1))
            findShortestPath(maze, visited, i, j - 1, x, y, min_dist, dist + 1, p_route, route.append("W") , rows,  columns);

        // Backtrack - Remove (i, j) from visited mazerix
        visited[i][j] = 0;
    
}

void userInput()
{
    string filename;
    int rows;
    int columns;
    cout << "Please input the name of your maze!" << endl;
    cin >> filename;
    cout << endl;
    cout << "Please input the amount of rows in your maze!" << endl;
    cin >> rows;
    cout << endl;
    cout << "Please input the amount of columns in your maze!" << endl;
    cin >> columns;
    cout << endl;
    createMaze(rows, columns, filename);


}

void createMaze(int rows, int columns, string filename)
{
    int startRow = 0;
    int startColumn = 0;
    int endRow = 0;
    int endColumn = 0;
    int column = 0;
    auto maze = std::vector<vector<char>>(rows, std::vector<char>(columns));    ifstream input(filename);
    char data = input.get();
    string route;
    string p_route;
    while (!input.eof())
    {
        for (int row = 0; row < rows; row++)
        {
            while (data != '\n' && !input.eof())
            {
                if (data == 'A')
                {
                    startRow = row;
                    startColumn = column;
                }
                if (data == 'B')
                {
                    endRow = row;
                    endColumn = column;
                }
                maze[row][column] = data;
                column++;
                data = input.get();
            }
            column = 0;

            data = input.get();
        }
    }
    input.close();
    cout << "The Maze being solved is: " << endl;
    for (int y = 0; y < rows; y++)
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < columns; x++)
        {
            cout << maze[y][x];
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    input.close();
    // construct a mazerix to keep track of visited cells
    auto visited = vector<vector<int>>(rows, vector<int>(columns));
    // initially all cells are unvisited


    int min_dist = INT_MAX;
    findShortestPath(maze, visited, startRow, startColumn, endRow, endColumn, min_dist, 0, p_route, route, rows,columns);
}
```

Comment: Look up: [Dijkstra Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm)

Comment: @MartinYork Pretty sure this is just dynamic programming filling all blanks one by one.

Comment: The code appears to be a DFS. What you want is either a BFS, or A*

Comment: @user3386109 can it not be solved using DFS at all?

Comment: I suppose it could be done with a DFS. But it would be like pounding on a nail with a screwdriver. Sure you can do it, but why would you?

Comment: @user3386109 It's only due to deadline constraints and I'm not sure if I have time to rebuild the code using BFS

Comment: While searching with a DFS, one of two things will happen. Either the DFS will reach a dead-end, or it will reach the goal. If it reaches a dead-end, that's just time wasted. If it reaches the goal, you have a path, but not necessarily the shortest path. Which means the code can't stop there. It literally needs to search every possible path while keeping track of the shortest one found. With a 1000x1000 maze, a BFS will finish in milliseconds, and a DFS will take days. That's the issue. If the maze is small enough, you can make a DFS work. Just explore every possible path.

Comment: When you reach the goal, the code should be `if (p_route.length() == 0 || route.length() < p_route.length()) { p_route = route; }` followed by a `return`. Then, in `createMaze` the code after `findShortestPath` should be `if (p_route.length() == 0) { cout << "bad"; } else { cout << p_route.length(); }`. You can get rid of `dist` and `min_dist` since they don't tell you anything that `p_route.length()` doesn't already tell you. But as I've already said, you should expect this solution to take a very long time if the maze is large.